# Automatically backup photos from iOS

Tags: images, ios, backup, photography

I'm looking for an iOS app to automatically backup photos. Perfect would be a solution which backups the photos to a server (e.g. a Raspberry PI) in my local network (via WiFi). But I'm also thinking about cloud-based solutions like Dropbox or GoogleDrive.

The most important points are:

- run automatically in the background
- only sync if WiFi is available
- possibility to access the photos on Linux and macOS (e.g. for importing in digiKam or Apple Photos)

Interesting (minor) questions:

- If a photo is removed from the backup will it be re-synced or not?
- How well does it handle meta data (like geo location)?
- Are videos or "Live Photos" supported?

Comment: Standard Google photos app ain't working for u? Basically it does a backup with searchable cloud stired base.

Comment: You could look at OwnCloud - you can run it on your server, and it has an iOS app for syncing.

Comment: tlo, any updates?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about live photos, but flickr, google photos, shoebox can all automatically sync your photos. All also have the option to sync only via wifi. They will only sync new photos in your library, so don't worry about having your old photos deleted.

If this is not working for you, you can also try IFTTT.

Answer (score 1):

Note I only use this software in a very limited environment. But, a suggestion could be: **OwnCloud**.

For user documentation on how to use OwnCloud for iOS, refer to [this web URL](https://doc.owncloud.org/ios/ios_app.html).

Setup OwnCloud via Raspberry Pi - [view the blog on TechRadar](http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/how-to-set-up-a-raspberry-pi-powered-cloud-service-1316017).

If you are not sure how to access OwnCloud (or your Pi) off your LAN, read [here](http://www.locslikes.com/remote-access/).

Does this software solution meet your needs?

- Run automatically? ...there seem to be [bugs](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=27218).
- Only Use WiFi? Just restrict the app from Mobile Data access unless you want to use it on data (I guess you could [chase these threads up](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=13237)..)
- Is the app cross-platform? Well yeah, even web-based!

Now in relation to your wants:

- Deleting photo from backup, does it re-sync? In my scenario, it does resync from my other device. Might need to chase up a "one-way sync" option wherein there is a 'master' and repository option. [Check this post out.](https://forum.syncthing.net/t/smartphone-photo-backup-to-server-sync-new-files-keep-deleted/2672)
- How well does it handle meta-data? Cannot help at all in this respect unfortunately (as I only use OwnCloud for PDFs I create). bit check this [Forum](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=32776) out.
- Does it support Live Files? [Sure](https://github.com/owncloud/ios/issues/578)....

Answer (score 1):

I use **Shoebox** and it works great. Very seamless. I'd forgotten I even used it until I read your post. I logged onto the site for only 2nd time ever and all my photos were there. I'd highly recommend [Shoebox](https://shoeboxapp.com)

Comment: Could you provide a link for the convenience of everyone else?

Answer (score 1):

I use the Google photos app, which does almost everything you want, although I'm not sure whether it covers your third requirement: "*possibility to access the photos on Linux and macOS (e.g. for importing in digiKam or Apple Photos)*"

Comment: Sorry for the late recommendation, I didn't check the OP date first.

Answer (score 1):

Give Lomorage a try, https://lomorage.com, it's free and cross platform.